# How to aggregate payout values by month from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

How to aggregate values by month and by date from this data frame:

```
payout_date payout_value
2017-01-14  1
2017-01-14  30
2017-01-16  216
2017-02-17  23
2017-02-17  2
2017-03-19  745
2017-03-19  32
2017-03-20  11
2017-03-20  222
2017-03-21  4
```

For daily aggregated values I used

```
df.groupby('date').agg(['sum'])

payout_value
sum
date    
2017-01-14  31
2017-01-16  216
2017-02-17  25
2017-03-19  777
2017-03-20  233
2017-03-21  4
```

How do I obtain monthly aggregated `payout value`?

```
payout_date payout_value
2017-01-14  247
2017-02-17  25
2017-03-19  1014
```

Comment: Did you try `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='payout_date', freq='M')).payount_value.sum()`? And similarly, `freq='D'` for daily aggregation.

Comment: Thanks, for monthly it worked perfectly. For daily, though, it inputs date values for every day, even if there is no corresponding values. For daily I also used df.groupby('date').agg(['sum'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one solution. Couple of points to note:

- When you use `pd.Grouper` with `freq='M'`, the `groupby` index becomes the last day of each month.
- For grouping by day, no conversion to a `pd.Grouper` object is necessary, though you can use `pd.Grouper` with `freq='D'` if you wish and filter out `NaN` values.

**Group by Month**

```
df['payout_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['payout_date'])

grouper = pd.Grouper(key='payout_date', freq='M')
res1 = df.groupby(grouper)['payout_value'].sum().reset_index()

print(res1)

   month  payout_value
0      1           247
1      2            25
2      3          1014
```

**Group by Day**

```
res2 = df.groupby('payout_date', as_index=False)['payout_value'].sum()

print(res2)

  payout_date  payout_value
0  2017-01-14            31
1  2017-01-16           216
2  2017-02-17            25
3  2017-03-19           777
4  2017-03-20           233
5  2017-03-21             4
```

Comment: Thank you! What would be the quickest way to plot 'payout_date' on x axis and 'payout_value' on y axis? or should I create another question. Thank you

Comment: @user40, No problem. I think best to ask your second question separately (if it hasn't been asked elsewhere on SO).